# Passing only 1 float in a sampler1D

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have multiple mesh that I want to draw in a `glDrawElementsInstanced`but I want all the vertices to all have a different height so to do this I'm trying to pass the height by a sampler1D.

This is how I create the texture :

```
    glGenTextures(1, &meshHeightTexId_);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, meshHeightTexId_);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // meshHeight_.size() = meshNumber_*meshSize_
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RED, meshNumber_*meshSize_, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, meshHeight_.data());

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
```

(meshNumber_ is the numbers of mesh, meshSize_ is the number of vertices is contain and meshHeight_ is a float vector containing all the height data)

The call I do before the draw :

```
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, meshHeightTexId_);
```

And in the shader I gather the value like this :

```
int index = gl_InstanceID * meshSize + gl_VertexID;
vec4 tempo = texture(heightData, index);
float height = tempo.r;
```

(heightData is the name of the sampler1D I use and meshSize is an uniform int containing the number of vertices in a mesh)

Then I use the height as the y value of the vertice.

But by doing this it look like I only get height equal to 0 (Exept 1 in an angle for no reason).

I may doing something wrong at the initialization of the texture..

And also if you have a better idea than passing the height of meshes by texture I would take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_TEXTURE_1D` uses normalized texture coordinates. Since you set `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` all values beyond [0, 1] will be clamped to that interval, so you get only the first and the last height value.

The function you're looking for is `texelFetch`:

```
vec4 tempo = texelFetch(heightData, index, 0);
```

Alternatively you can create a UBO and read the data from an array within.

Comment: Damn, I totally forgot about that interval in texture coordinates ! Thanks.
And what's the best between using an UBO and a sampler in term of performance ? (I'm learning openGL and I never heard of UBO, I'm gonna read a bit about it)

Comment: @GuillaumeMagniadas: I don't know about the performance, but to my understanding reading the vertex data from a UBO (or SSBO?) based on InstanceID/VertexID is pretty much what VAOs are under the hood.